Strongly typing eagerly loaded navigation properties with EF Core
How do you handle Service calls that expect parameters to have navigation properties to be prefetched and thus not null?
Lets say we have an ASP.Net Core App with explicit nullability and EF Core with eager loading configured.
We get out data from our data layer and process it in different services in our Business layer.
Lets say we have a Service with this interface:
interface IBlogInterface
{
  int GetInfoAboutBlogEntry(BlogEntry entry);
}

And BlogEntry has a required (non null) navigation propery called Author which this service expects to be preloaded with .Include(x=>x.Author).
How can we denote this requirement such that the compiler can tell us before runtime that it will fail if we call this service with data gathered from a datalayer-service that does not prefetch the author.
Because we modeled our author to be Author author and not Author? author the compiler will not complain, as it expects the author to exist, but EF Core sets it to null! which will throw a runtime exception when trying to access it.
The obvious solution would obviously just be to not pass around DB Objects that require preloads and only hand the service the id/key of the blogentry and let it gather the entry with the data on its own. But what if i have multiple services which expect the same data and i want to only fetch it once and thus make the caller of the services responsible for gathering the data once and passing it to each service?
I thought about creating subtypes like BlogEntryWithPreloadedAuthor, but this does not really scale with nested Includes eg BlogEntryWithPreloadedAuthorWithPreloadedAddress_WithPreloadedComments.
The other thing would be to announce through documentation what data the Service expects to be preloaded, but that is not enforced by the compiler and could lead to errors when refactoring etc.

The description is too verbose and lacks important information or code snippets. Please rephrase the question for better clarity and include relevant code examples.

EF Entities serve data domain, not transport, so IMHO it is best to use dedicated transport objects (DTOs) suited to the required and optional details needed in transport.  Barring that, EF and null-able checks with .Net you can opt for making the property Nullable to keep the null check happy, and use the [Required] attribute to keep EF happy that it shouldn't be #null when inserting new values into the table.
